# Can two version of resteasy & jetty be loaded in same JVM

Tags: rest, resteasy

I have a very typical problem. I am using in-house developed platform which uses Jetty server and rest easy to provide a wrapper over REST framework. When they did that they made lot of tweaks for some specific scenes.

Now problem is that when I developed a REST based service with raw interfaces of rest easy and embed my jetty server in same JVM. My service can receive the request but response is always 500 server error.

I feel the in-house framework is intercepting the response doing some security validations so my response doesn't reach.

I was wondering if there is a way to use the different rest easy version and run in same JVM. I have tried to embed a jetty server and added a normal Servlet and I can access it but I can't achieve the same with my rest based servlet.

Any Idea how could I load two versions of rest easy on same JVM ?

Answer (score 0):

What you can't have is two applications in the same web application context, since you are supposed to define only one class implementing `javax.ws.rs.Application`.

But that shouldn't be a problem, as long as classes live in different ClassLoaders. Each web application context [**must** be in isolation of other contexts](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/servlet-3.0-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/), each defining its own ClassLoader.

You can perform all kinds of class loading manipulation in Jetty: https://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Reference/Jetty_Classloading

In conclusion, as long as you use different jar files of RESTEasy in each web context, you should be able to run two REST applications using different RESTEasy versions in the same JVM process.

Comment: Actually when I launch the jetty server , I provide the new context. I tried launching multiple Application in sme JVM with different context it worked. Looks like this issue is in our in house frame.